# Share post on Youtube

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, link, youtube, help-wanted

I'm trying to create a share button on a youtube post, but I haven't found a solution yet. The problem I'm having is that the youtube share link is the same as that of fb: [http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u={url}](http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=%7Burl%7D), how do I do that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not related to Magento.

Comment: @ Ubed Shaikh
 No bro, maybe my English is bad so I can't make it clear

Comment: Do you need to create a button the same as the Facebook share button in Magento and share your video on youtube? am I right?

Comment: @ViralPatel Yes, but the problem I have is that youtube is not like fb that has a share link like http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u={url} and then just add the link of my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's out of box functinality.

**It's not possible** to share page in youtube. You can share only videos in Youtube. Not possible to share any page or post in Youtube.

Comment: Oh that's it, thank you, turns out I can only share videos on youtube